# Percentile of every column and row in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, percentile

I have a csv that looks like the image below. I want to calculate the percentile(10,50,90) of each row starting from B2 to X2 and adding that final percentile in a new column. Essentially, I want to find the 10th percetile of the average(std, cv, sp_tim.....) value over the entire period of record available.   [image]

I have created the following code line to read it in python as a dataframe format so far.

```
da = pd.read_csv('Project/11433300_annual_flow_matrix.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly then below code might be helpful for you:

I have Used some Dummy data, and given similar kind of treatment on it which you are looking for

```
aq = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11]
aw = [91, 25, 13, 53, 95, 94, 75, 35, 57, 88, 111, 12]
df = pd.DataFrame({'aq': aq, 'aw': aw})

n = df.shape[0]
p = 0.1 #for 10th percentile
position = np.ceil(n*p)
position = int(position)
df.iloc[position,]
```

Kindly have a look and let me know if this is works for you.